# How to make MS Word number captioned images from left to right instead of right to left

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I'm using the caption feature in MS Word 2013 to automatically number some images. The problem I'm having is that when I have multiple images at the same height across a page, word is numbering them from right to left and I want them numbered from left to right. Is there a way to change this aside from manually editing them or having the images set slightly lower across the page?

[image: Figures have been numbered from right to left]

Comment: Have you thought about putting the images in a table (without borders) with each picture in a separate cell?